# Clicking a cell to fire a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I came across the following VBA for generating a msgbox when clicking a certain cell:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Hello World"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works great, however what is the syntax to add another in straight after?
Ie, clicking a different cell to get a different message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to handle two cells:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Selection.Count = 1 Then
      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Hello World"
      End If

      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F5")) Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Goodby World"
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```